# Is it possible to write i file to the computers file system from the iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to save an camera image from my application to the desktop so i can preview it. is it possible? The images that comes with the simulator seems to be too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so, the idea of the iPhone is that it's entirely sandboxed. Your application has its own little area to manipulate data in and do what you need to do.

From the sounds of it you are using the camera API to take a picture? Maybe you can save the generated image to your /Resources/ folder and look at it that way (just use Finder to browse through your Xcode projects directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can't write files directly to an attached computer from an iPhone app. You *can* save images to the Camera Roll, and they can then be transferred from the iPhone to your computer using iPhoto.